# DB2 group results for records where dates overlap

Tags: sql, date, group-by, db2, overlap

I am trying to write a query which groups the records together on particular fields.  I need the grouping to take into account where dates overlap so if records 1-5 had the same grouping values but only 1,3,4 had date ranges that overlap each other then 1,3 and 4 would form one group and 2 and 5 would fall into another grouping.

An outline of the SQL so far is below and struggling to work out the best way to approach this.

```
SELECT MIN(STARTDATE),
       MAX(ENDDATE),
       PRIORITY,
       CLASS,
       HARDWARE,
       BAND,
       COST
FROM TABLE1
GROUP BY PRIORITY,
         CLASS,
         HARDWARE,
         BAND,
         COST
```

Comment: ... what happens if there are gaps among members of the group?  Ie, rows 1 and 3 don't overlap with each other, but they both overlap with 2?  This type of analysis tends to be slow and consume a lot of resource, regardless.

Comment: Yeah, in that scenario then all 3 need to be in the same group.  If 2 started after 1 ended then 1 would be in one group and 2 and 3 would be in another.

Comment: oh, and importantly, what platform/version of DB2?  Windowing functions are likely to be helpful here.

Comment: The version I am using is IBM DB2 Version 10.1 for Linux, UNIX, and Windows